# Is it possible to prevent Gradle from adding excluded transitive dependency?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java library built using Gradle 5.6 with some transitive dependencies suppressed

```
api('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}
```

When I publish it to Maven repo I get a corresponding section of `POM.xml`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

But when I add my library as a dependency also using Gradle 5.6

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'my.group:my.lib:1.0.0'
}
```

I see the excluded dependency (e.g., `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`) appearing in my `compileClasspath` configuration. Is there any way to exclude it once and for all or should I instead do it in all projects that use my library manually?

Comment: When you list dependencies with `gradle -q dependencies` do you see that `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` is being pulled by `my.lib`?

Comment: Yep, it appears both in `compileClasspath` and `runtime` configurations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the docs (emphasis mine):

> Excluding a particular transitive dependency **does not guarantee that it does not show up in the dependencies of a given configuration**. For example, some other dependency, which does not have any exclude rules, might pull in exactly the same transitive dependency. **To guarantee that the transitive dependency is excluded from the entire configuration please use per-configuration exclude rules: Configuration.getExcludeRules()**. In fact, in majority of cases the actual intention of configuring per-dependency exclusions is really excluding a dependency from the entire configuration (or classpath).

Rather then specifying an exclusion rule for each configuration, you can apply the rule to all configurations:

```
// Kotlin DSL
configurations.all {
    exclude(mapOf("module" to "spring-boot-starter-logging"))
    exclude(mapOf("module" to "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"))
}
```